# Git files not the same within finder (Mac Yosemite)

Tags: git, macos, repository, finder

I pull the master branch from github repo - the files and folders show as per.

However, when I change branch from "master" to "development" the folders are not updated which I don't understand why.

Within Sublime Text 3 they have updated but not within Finder on my Mac.

I'm switching branch via terminal using "`git checkout development`" and the folder structure is the same as the master branch.

Any ideas as to why this might be?

Mac version: Yosemite - 10.10.5

Comment: After doing "`git checkout development`", what happens when you do "`git pull origin development`"?  Do you get a bunch of new / different files then?

Comment: Hi Michael - thanks for your comment. The issue was with Finder not refreshing. Check my answer below if you have the same issue on the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution - I  had to enable show hidden files. Bizarre but it works instantly.

In terminal paste the following: defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES

Press return

Hold the 'Option/alt' key, then right click on the Finder icon in the dock and click Relaunch.

Happy days!